# How to fix an output of a simulation, output “U”

Tags: vhdl

I tested one my assumptions and wrote for that the following simulation:

The simulation should detect a falling edge and rising edge of the `spi_clk`

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity main is

    Port (
        clk      : in  std_logic; 
        rst      : in  std_logic; 
        spi_clk     : in  std_logic; 
        spi_cs     : in  std_logic; 
        test_output : out std_logic
        --spi_mosi     : in  std_logic

    );
end entity;

architecture Behavioral of main is


    signal spi_clk_b          : std_logic;
    signal spi_cs_b          : std_logic;
   -- signal mosi_b          : std_logic;
    signal spi_clk_bb           : std_logic;
    signal spi_cs_bb           : std_logic;
    --signal mosi_bb          : std_logic;
    signal spi_clk_redge_en   : std_logic;
    signal spi_clk_fedge_en   : std_logic;
    signal spi_clk_bbb: std_logic;
    

begin

    sync_ffs_p : process (clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            spi_clk_b <= spi_clk;
            spi_cs_b <= spi_cs;
          --  mosi_b <= spi_mosi;
            spi_clk_bb  <= spi_clk_b;
            spi_cs_bb  <= spi_cs_b;
            --mosi_bb  <= mosi_b;
        end if;
    end process;


    spi_clk_reg_p : process (clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if (rst = '1') then
                spi_clk_bbb <= '0';
            else
                spi_clk_bbb <= spi_clk_bb;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;


    -- Falling edge is detect when spi_clk_reg=0 and spi_clk_reg=1.
    spi_clk_redge_en <= not spi_clk_bb and spi_clk_bbb;
    -- Rising edge is detect when spi_clk_reg=1 and spi_clk_reg=0.
    spi_clk_redge_en <= spi_clk_bb and not spi_clk_bbb;
    
   process (clk)
        begin
            if (rising_edge(clk)) then
                if (rst = '0') then
                   if spi_clk_fedge_en = '1' then
                    test_output <= '0';
                   elsif  spi_clk_redge_en = '1' then 
                    test_output <= '1';
                   end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
    
end Behavioral;
```

The corresponding simulation has a test bench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity tb is
--  Port ( );
end tb;

architecture Behavioral of tb is

signal clk :std_logic;
signal rst: std_logic;
signal spi_clk: std_logic;
signal spi_cs: std_logic;
signal test_output : std_logic;
constant clk_period : time := 20 ns ;
constant spi_clk_period : time := 100 ns;

begin

dut : entity work.main

port map (
    clk      => clk,
    rst      => rst,
    spi_clk  => spi_clk,
    spi_cs   => spi_cs,
   -- spi_mosi     => spi_mosi,
    test_output  =>test_output
    );
    
clk_gen_p : process
begin
clk <= '0';
wait for clk_period/2;
clk <= '1';
wait for clk_period/2;
end process;
            
spi_clk_gen_p : process
begin
spi_clk <= '0';
wait for spi_clk_period/2;
spi_clk <= '1';
wait for spi_clk_period/2;
end process;

process
begin
spi_cs <='1';
wait for 300 ns;
spi_cs <= '0';
wait for 2850 ns;
end process;
rst <=  '1', '0' after 10ns;


end Behavioral;`
```

The VHDL editor gives me the following result:
[image]

As you can see it doesn't give me the correct output. The simulation seems easy. I couldn't find a mistake.

What is my mistake?

Comment: @Mat thank you for your comment. I have used your suggestion but it doesnt help to fix my problem

Comment: Add the internal signals to the simulation and see which ones are OK and where it goes wrong. Perhaps an edge detector that takes longer than half a period of the signal it's detecting is not such a good idea.

Comment: Edge detector is simply XOR consecutive samples of clock sampling the clock value for determining polarity with over sampling ratio to determine max delay of edge detection. Or using analog XOR for smallest delay.

Comment: And why not you debug the dut internal signals and show the same in the waveforms? You have to dig deeper....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

```
       if spi_clk_fedge_en = '1' then
        test_output <= '0';
       elsif  spi_clk_redge_en = '1' then 
        test_output <= '1';
       end
```

Clean up the logic and it should work. The other problem with this statement is you have two processes that are not clocked (asynchronous logic) that you use to develop clocked logic. This can be bad because gate delays from the non clocked logic  (this statement: `spi_clk_redge_en <= spi_clk_bb and not spi_clk_bbb;`) is most likely causing indeterminate states as the reset is always happening on the clock and the edge signals are happening with a delay after the clock edge. Note the following code is not perfect and I don't know what your intention is, the following code is for demonstration purposes.

So clock the `spi_clk_redge_en <= spi_clk_bb and not spi_clk_bbb;` statement OR clean up the logic OR look for the third option

Also to write good code and make sure it works also provide else cases for everything:

```
          if (rst = '0') then
               if spi_clk_fedge_en = '1' then
                test_output <= '0';
               elsif  spi_clk_redge_en = '1' then 
                test_output <= '1';
               else
                test_output <= '0'; -- or whatever
               end if;
          else
               test_output <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
```

this way you will always know what your going to get, generally synthesizers are good about this but you never know.

Other option, this option removes the unclocked signals from the clocked reset signal and puts them in the sensitivity list, letting the synthesizer know they are not clocked and they over ride any clocked signals :

```
  process (clk,spi_clk_fedge_en,spi_clk_redge_en )
        begin
            if spi_clk_fedge_en = '1' then
                    test_output <= '0';
            elsif  spi_clk_redge_en = '1' then 
                    test_output <= '1';         
            elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
                if (rst = '0') then

                  test_output <= '0';
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
```

Comment: my goal is detect falling edge of spi clock. I simulate spi slave